# Open a Downloaded file (pdf) from the Downloads folder in the INTERNAL STORAGE

Tags: android, file, pdf, android-intent, android-download-manager

I have downloaded a file (133465.pdf) using the Download manager and now it is stored in the Downloads folder of the mobile phone (Internal storage).

How should i try and retrieve the downloaded pdf from the Downloads folder?

I am using the below code to try and retrieve the pdf from the downloads folder but i am getting an error on the Toast, saying "Cannot display PDF (133465.pdf cannot be opened)" .

```
String file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() +  File.separator + "133465.pdf";
                Log.i("Fragmentadapter1", file);
                File videoFile2Play = new File(file);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(videoFile2Play), "application/pdf");
                imageContext.startActivity(i);
```

I don't know if i am using the right file location to access the file.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are working for Lollopop and Below: You don't have to ask the user for permission on run-time. The manifest Permissions will do.

If you are working for Marshmellow and up: You have to ask the user for [permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) on run-time and act according to the users output.

Remember: You still have to give the Permissions on the Manifest too.

**To Download a PDF on users Downloads folder :**

```
DownloadManager downloadmanager;
    Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            .mkdirs();

    downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    String url = hardcode + bb ;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setTitle(bb )
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                    bb)
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    Log.i("Download1", String.valueOf(request));
    downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

[Reference](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/download-manager-in-android-with-example.html#.V3zXH_krK01)

**To View the Downloaded PDF from the Downloads folder of the Users device:**

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + File.separator +
            "YOUR FILE NAME");
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Log.i("Fragment2", String.valueOf(path));
    Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    try {
        this.startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    }
```

**Note: Make sure u get the permission granted before downloading the Viewing the PDF file for Marshmellow and UP.**

Comment: download fail.. any idea why it happens?

Comment: Its working fine but .There is an issue regarding the "Environment.getExterbalStoragePublicDirectory" gives deprected file.Please update new code.