# Read file from Download folder and write it's content to the list of String

Tags: java, android

I have problem with this android app. I am trying to write an app that sends one sms to many phone numbers. After press Send button an app loads phone numbers from file input.txt situated in internal downloads folder of the phone, and then using loop it sends as many sms as numbers into input.txt file. Now I am stuck when trying to read data from text file situated in Downloads folder and convert it's content to the list of Strings.
I am getting an error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: Download/input.txt
```

This is my method :

```
private List<String> readTextFromUri() throws IOException {
        List<String> phones = new ArrayList<>();
        try (InputStream inputStream =
                     getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(Uri.parse(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/input.txt"));
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(inputStream)))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                phones.add(line);
            }
        }
        return phones;
    }
```

Comment: That is no valid path indeed. Environment class offers them.

Comment: Check this question & answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104713/open-a-downloaded-file-pdf-from-the-downloads-folder-in-the-internal-storage

Comment: I read it and changed a code, but now I get Access Denied error